# Rubymine break when Exception thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

In RubyMine, is there a way to break at the line that caused the exception whenever an exception is thrown. In Visual Studio this is the default behavior for many types of exceptions.

I am stuck on Rubymine version 6.3.3 as the upgrade licence expired.

Comment: Try this: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/creating-exception-breakpoints.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hidden in the UI, but you can use Ruby Exception Breakpoints as explained here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/creating-exception-breakpoints.html